# what is the error in this following code?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm a beginner of iOS. When I'm using Core Data to my sample project, it gives me a thread error.

Please help me to solve this error.

Here's my code:

```
-(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultController{
if (self.fetchedResultController != nil ) {
    return self.fetchedResultController;
}

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recepie" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[request setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"recepieName" ascending:YES];

NSArray *sortDescriptorArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor,nil];

request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptorArray;

self.fetchedResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest: request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

self.fetchedResultController.delegate = self;

return self.fetchedResultController;

}
```

Comment: looks like a problem with your Keys/value pairs.

Comment: Yeah.It's seems to be like that

Comment: is your `Recepie` and `recepieName` correct?

Comment: Can you post the error so we can see what your actual error is.

Comment: " _fetchedResultController NSFetchedResultsController * nil". This is the error message

Comment: @pappy well the Michal Ciuba's answer should be correct.

Answer (score 6):

When you refer to a property using dot notation like this

```
if (self.fetchedResultController != nil ) {
    return self.fetchedResultController;
}
```

it is equivalent to calling `[self fetchedResultController]` method (which is the getter for this property).  And when you do this, you already *are* inside the getter, so the method infinitely calls itself, leading to the [Stack overflow error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

You should not use the dot notation for getting a property value (using setter is OK). Use a [backing variable](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW2) instead:

```
if(_fetchedResultController != nil) {
    return _fetchedResultController;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the following code.

```
  -(NSFetchedResultsController*)fetchedResultController{
   if (self.fetchedResultController != nil ) {
        return self.fetchedResultController;
    }

   NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc]init];
   NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

   NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recepie" inManagedObjectContext:context];

   [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"recepieName"  ascending:YES];

    NSArray *sortDescriptorArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor,nil];

    request.sortDescriptors = sortDescriptorArray;

    self.fetchedResultController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:    request managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

    self.fetchedResultController.delegate = self;

    error = nil;

    if (![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }

   return self.fetchedResultController;
}
```